# Docker on Ubuntu 15.10 32 bit (OS and Processor)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, docker, containers

Is there a way to install Docker on my 32 bit Ubuntu (with 32 bit Processor)?

I tried the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install docker.io
```

It appears to be installing. But I get the old version of Docker (1.6.x)
From one another thread, I read that docker.io is a repo maintained by Ubuntu and so it may not be up to date.

I tried setting up Docker repo as mentioned in Docker docs, and tried to install with the following command. It does not seem to work.

```
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

Also tried

```
sudo apt-get install docker
```

It does not seem to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Dockerfile already present in the Docker github. Modify the base image to use 32-bit image. I have written a blog post which you can follow to build one:
http://nirmata.com/2016/02/docker-daemon-for-x32-architectures/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`git clone https://github.com/docker-32bit/ubuntu.git
cd ubuntu
bash build-image.sh`

This worked for me. The only caveat is that I need to run all the docker commands using sudo now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Docker's Ubuntu installation manual?

It can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/

According to the documentation, it is not possible to install docker on 32-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: I see that some are successful using it. But the documentation is sparse.